# Trying to put an ActionListener on a button then make it paint text

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, paint

Im still pretty new to java and I wrote a magic 8 ball program awhile ago. Well I just learned about JFrames and JPanels, so i wanted to update it.
 Im having trouble with a couple of things, and i dont know if this is asking too much because of never used this website before. i dont understand actionlisteners too well and i need help  putting one on the b button to make it paint a new JPanel that paints my random chooser statements. That's the other thing, how do i make it paint one of my array elements?

### `window`

```
   package pack;
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
 import javax.swing.*;

 public class window extends ball  {
 public static void main (String []args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("hello");
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    JLabel l = new JLabel("What do you ask the magic conch shell?");
    JTextField t = new JTextField(25);
    JButton b = new JButton();

    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                        }
           });
        //panel
    b.setText("Ask");
    p.add(l);
    p.add(b);
    p.add(t);

    //frame
    f.add(p);
    f.setSize(300, 400);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setVisible(true);
    }}
```

### `ball`

```
     package pack;

    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Random;

    public class ball  {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
     String question = ("What do you ask the Magic Conch shell?");
      Scanner userInput =new Scanner(System.in);
       String answer = userInput.nextLine();

    String[] array;
     array = new String[8];
     array[0] = ("yes");
     array[1] = ("no");
     array[2] = ("maybe");
     array[3] = ("never");
     array[4] = ("ask again later");
     array[5] = ("positive");
     array[6] = ("unlikely");
     array[7] = ("yes");

     Random dice = new Random();
     int n = dice.nextInt(8);
     System.out.println(array[n]);
    }
    }
```

Comment: sorry i just edited it

Comment: `make it paint a new JPanel that paints my random chooser statements` - why do you need to paint anything on a panel? Just use a JLabel to display the text. So you create a simple JFrame with the components you want. You can set the JLabel to just display " " (a single space). Then in your ActionListener you just set the text of the label to whatever value you want.

Answer (score 0):

Take the code from your `ball` class, use it to create a method which returns the result of the roll, this provides you a point of re-use

```
public class Ball {

    private String[] results = new String[] {
        "yes", "no", "maybe", "never", "ask again later", "postive", "unlikely", "yes"
    };

    private Random random = new Random();

    public String roll() {
        int n = random.nextInt(results.length);
        return results[n];
    }

}
```

Now, in your buttons `ActionListener`, you need to "roll" the ball

```
Ball ball = new Ball();
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                        
        String result = ball.roll();
    }
});
```

Now, you next problem is, you don't actually have anywhere to display the result.

You really don't want to introduce a new component at this stage if you can help it, instead, you want to have one ready to use, so, let's add another `JLabel` to act as the "answer"

```
Ball ball = new Ball();
JLabel answer = new JLabel("...");
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String result = ball.roll();
        answer.setText(result); 
    }
});
//panel
b.setText("Ask");
p.add(l);
p.add(b);
p.add(t);
p.add(answer);
```

Adding components at runtime isn't difficult, but it does introduce a number of other issues you need to aware of. In this, we've limited some of the issues by introducing a component which we can simply update as needed